# How to make a moving graph in Javascript P5

Tags: javascript, arrays, animation, graph, p5.js

I have struggled to make my a moving graph in P5. My idea is to make a graph by the length of an array. If the length of the array increases the graph will move up and if it increases it will do the opposite.

My code can be seen at this [link](https://editor.p5js.org/Mohammad/sketches/uzCnEN_oG), where I have made a comment,  where the graph is.

Answer (score 0):

[This example](https://discourse.processing.org/t/how-to-make-a-moving-graph-in-javascript-p5/19630/2) from @solub really highlights this issue, and presents a decent solution to the problem.

```
const W = 680, H = 200; // dimensions of canvas
const time = 400; // number of x tick values
const step = W/time; // time step

let data = []; // to store number of infected people
let count = 0; // steps counter
let pos, fy, c, infected, colors, l, f;


function setup() {
  createCanvas(W, H);
  fill(255, 30, 70, 90);

  // array containing the x positions of the line graph, scaled to fit the canvas
  posx = Float32Array.from({ length: time }, (_, i) => map(i, 0, time, 0, W));

  // function to map the number of infected people to a specific height (here the height of the canvas)
  fy = _ => map(_, 3, 0, H, 10);

  // colors based on height stored in an array list.
  colors = d3.range(H).map(i => d3.interpolateWarm(norm(i, 0, H)))

}

function draw() {
  background('#fff');

  // length of data list -1 (to access last item of data list)
  l = data.length -1 ;

  // frameCount
  f = frameCount;

  // number of infected people (noised gaussian curved)
  c = sin(f*0.008);
  infected = (exp(-c*c/2.0) / sqrt(TWO_PI) / 0.2)  + map(noise(f*0.02), 0, 1, -1, 1);


  // store that number at each step (the x-axis tick values)
  if (f&step) {
    data.push(infected);
    count += 1;
  }


  // iterate over data list to rebuild curve at each frame
  for (let i = 0; i < l; i++) {

    y1 = fy(data[i]);
    y2 = fy(data[i+1]);
    x1 = posx[i];
    x2 = posx[i+1];

    // vertical lines (x-values)
    strokeWeight(0.2);
    line(x1, H, x1, y1 + 2);

    // polyline
    strokeWeight(2);
    stroke(colors[Math.floor(map(y1, H, 10, H, 0))] );
    line(x1, y1, x2, y2);

  }

  // draw ellispe at last data point
  if (count > 1) {
    ellipse(posx[l], fy(data[l]), 4, 4);
  }

  // reset data and count
  if (count%time===0) {
    data = [];
    count = 0;
  }

}
```